# Columns with a table at left and an image at right are not responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have the following code using bootstrap 4.

I want to split vertically a row with 2 columns.

At left there is a table which is not functioning responsively and shows a vertical scrollbar

At right there is an image with a bigger width than user's screen and it also is not functioning responsively and makes the whole page to be scrolled at right till it reach the right end of the image instead of being resized according to screen view.

[**Codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xYpvMB?editors=1000) -> Check it on large screens < 1920px.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <h3 class="about-villa">subtitle</h3>
        <table class="table table-responsive">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
              </th>
              <th>
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
              </th>
              <th>
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
              </th>
              <th>
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
              </th>
              <th>
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
              </th>
              <th>
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>Image title</td>
              <td>Image title</td>
              <td>Image title</td>
              <td>Image title</td>
              <td>Image title</td>
              <td>Image title</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1980x700/b5b5b5/ffffff&text=right+image+to+fit/width" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap 4 has changed image responsive class from img-responsive to img-fluid.

So the image class should be img-fluid.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                                <h4>Title</h4>
                                <h3 class="about-villa">subtitle</h3>
                                <table class="table table-responsive">
                                        <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                        <th>
                                                                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-fluid">
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-fluid">
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-fluid">
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-fluid">
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-fluid">
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-fluid">
                                                        </th>
                                                </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                        <td>Image title</td>
                                                        <td>Image title</td>
                                                        <td>Image title</td>
                                                        <td>Image title</td>
                                                        <td>Image title</td>
                                                        <td>Image title</td>
                                                </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                </table>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1980x700/b5b5b5/ffffff&text=right+image+to+fit/width" class="img-fluid">
                </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to wrap your table into a div having `table-responsive` class....Using `table-responsive` in `table` will not do anything as `overflow` not works on `table`...*[[Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/tables/#responsive-tables)]*

And there is no more `img-responsive` class in bootstrap4 use `img-fluid` instead...*[[Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/#responsive-images)]*

[**Codepen Link ▸**](https://codepen.io/bhuwanb9/pen/OQQLXg?editors=1000)

Answer (score 0):

The main idea is to create two div elements: one for left side (`style="float:left;"`) and another for right(`style="float:right`"). And then wrap them into one div. Also to manage img size you can do something like `style="height: auto; width: auto; max-width: 300px; max-height: 300px;"`
So I changed a bit your example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div >
        <div class="container-fluid">
                <div style="float: left;">
                                <h4>Title</h4>
                                <h3 class="about-villa">subtitle</h3>
                                <table style="float: left;">
                                        <thead>
                                                <tr>
                                                        <th>
                                                                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
                                                        </th>
                                                        <th>
                                                                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/170x120/b5b5b5/ffffff" class="img-responsive">
                                                        </th>
                                                </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                                <tr>
                                                        <td>Image title</td>
                                                        <td>Image title</td>
                                                        <td>Image title</td>
                                                        <td>Image title</td>
                                                        <td>Image title</td>
                                                        <td>Image title</td>
                                                </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                </table>
                </div>
                <div style="float: right;">
                        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/1980x700/b5b5b5/ffffff&text=right+image+to+fill+height/width" class="img-responsive" style="height: auto; width: auto; max-width: 300px; max-height: 300px;">
                </div>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```